# Keras Face Recognition model bad accuracy

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, face-recognition

I am struggling for some days to create my own model for face recognition with Keras in python. I will walk you through my setup and give you my code, I'm sure there is something I'm not doing right but I can't tell what. So, my dataset is composed of 97 people with an average of 10 photos per person. The total number of photos is 1106. The dataset is in a folder "faces" and the pictures for each person are in folders named from 0 to 96. Here is the code I am using to process and split my data into train, validation and test and also to create my CNN using Keras. Any help or suggestions are much appreciated, thank you!

```
channels = 3
rows = 50
cols = 50

classes = 97

data = []
labels = []

images = sorted(list(paths.list_images("faces")))

for image in images:
    img = cv2.imread(image)
    img = cv2.resize(img, (rows, cols)).flatten()
    data.append(img)

    label = image.split(os.path.sep)[-2]
    labels.append(label)

data = np.array(data, dtype="float32") / 255.0

labels = [int(i) for i in labels]
labels = np.array(labels)

xtrain, testX, ytrain, testY = train_test_split(data, labels, test_size = 0.3, random_state = 13)
trainX, validX, trainY, validY = train_test_split(xtrain, ytrain, test_size = 0.2, random_state = 14)

lb = LabelBinarizer()
trainY = lb.fit_transform(trainY)
validY = lb.transform(validY)
testY = lb.transform(testY)

trainX = trainX.astype("float32")
validX = validX.astype("float32")
testX = testX.astype("float32")
trainY = trainY.astype("float32")
validY = validY.astype("float32")
testY = testY.astype("float32")

trainX = trainX.reshape([trainX.shape[0], cols, rows, channels])
validX = validX.reshape([validX.shape[0], cols, rows, channels])
testX = testX.reshape([testX.shape[0], cols, rows, channels])

weight_decay = 1e-4
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3,3), padding='same', kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(weight_decay), input_shape=trainX.shape[1:]))
model.add(Activation('elu'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3,3), padding='same', kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(weight_decay)))
model.add(Activation('elu'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(Conv2D(64, (3,3), padding='same', kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(weight_decay)))
model.add(Activation('elu'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3,3), padding='same', kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(weight_decay)))
model.add(Activation('elu'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.3))

model.add(Conv2D(128, (3,3), padding='same', kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(weight_decay)))
model.add(Activation('elu'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Conv2D(128, (3,3), padding='same', kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(weight_decay)))
model.add(Activation('elu'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.4))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(classes))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))

datagen = ImageDataGenerator(horizontal_flip=True,
                             featurewise_center=False,
                             samplewise_center=False,
                             featurewise_std_normalization=False,
                             samplewise_std_normalization=False,
                             zca_whitening=False,
                             rotation_range=20,
                             width_shift_range=0.2,
                             height_shift_range=0.2,
                             vertical_flip=False)
datagen.fit(trainX)

optim = RMSprop(lr=0.001, decay=1e-6)
#sgd = SGD(lr=0.01, momentum=0.9)

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=optim, metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit_generator(datagen.flow(trainX, trainY, batch_size=64), steps_per_epoch = trainX.shape[0], epochs = 50, validation_data=(validX, validY), verbose = 1)
score = model.evaluate(testX, testY, batch_size = 64, verbose = 1)

print("Test score: ", score[0])
print("Test accuracy: ", score[1])

model_json = model.to_json()
open('face_architecture.json', 'w').write(model_json)
model.save_weights('face_weights.h5', overwrite=True)
```

Comment: You have to provide a little bit more information. How long are you training for, is your training loss converging?

Comment: I use 50 epochs when I train, and the loss at the end is somewhere around 0.14-0.13, problem is that the accuracy for validation at each epoch does not go above 0.45-0.48 and the accuracy for test is below 0.40

Comment: using dropout with convolutions can have some very questionable consequences. Look it up. Have you tried it without the dropout?

Comment: I will give it a try without dropout, and I forgot to mention that the validation loss is not converging, at every epoch is fluctuating between 3 and 2, so definitely not values under 1, could this be overfitting? And if it is, what options do I have? Thanks a lot, I am pretty new at this.

Comment: Actually, one more thing. Batch-norm should be between the convolution and the activation, not after. So in this case convolution - batch norm - elu.    source: http://cs231n.stanford.edu/slides/2017/cs231n_2017_lecture6.pdf

Comment: I tried your suggestions, and I also tried other configurations without dropout, but still, I cannot get values under 2 for the validation loss. The training accuracy grows pretty quickly to 0.90+, after 5 epochs and the training loss is below 1 at the same point. By the end, the training accuracy is almost 0.99 and training loss below 0.2, but validation results never go above 0.50 and test results are between 0.40-0.55 depending on the configuration.